# Selenium 4.5 Grid node with firefox/geckodriver not working as expected

Tags: firefox, selenium-grid

I'm trying to automate firefox browser with webdriverio, connecting it to a selenium 4.5 grid, however, I'm seeing the following error on the Grid node:

```
Response code 400. Message: Argument --remote-debugging-port can't be set via capabilities
```

I'm pointing to a localhost instance of selenium 4.5 hub with its node. Same node with chrome capability works for Google Chrome execution

Now, if I remove the host/port specification in the wdio.conf.ts and take the local hub down, I'm able to run firefox, albeit  after installing puppeteer and  having the firefox binary with nightly in the name.

(Researched and got it working with the following minimal 'Capabilities' configuration in wdio.conf.ts)

```
{
            browserName: 'firefox',
            'moz:firefoxOptions': {
                binary: '/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-nightly',
                           
            }
}
```

My assumption is that I should be able to get it working without puppeteer, on a remote machine which has the required node with firefox capabilities

I've referred to https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/configuration/cli_options/ and checked out --driver-configuration as well as a config file (toml) like:

```
[node]
detect-drivers = false
[[node.driver-configuration]]
max-sessions = 1
display-name = "Firefox"
stereotype = "{\"browserName\": \"firefox\", \"browserVersion\": \"105.0.1\", \"platformName\": \"MAC\", \"moz:firefoxOptions\": {\"binary\": \"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-nightly\"}}"
webdriver-executable = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'
```

(I have a softlink pointing firefox-nightly to the original binary works with puppeteer as stated above .. tried original binary as well for the node configuration)

Can someone share the correct configuration/dependencies/links of a selenium grid 4.5 configuration/ option  that will work?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I added the toml file like this for a windows node:

```
C:\grid>java -jar selenium-server-4.5.0.jar node --publish-events tcp://myserver:6656 --subscribe-events tcp://myserver:6657 --config firefox.toml
```

and in the toml file I defined:

```
[node]
detect-drivers = false
[[node.driver-configuration]]
display-name = "Firefox"
webdriver-executable = "C:\\\\grid\\geckodriver.exe"
max-sessions = 2
stereotype = "{\"browserName\": \"firefox\", \"browserVersion\": \"102.3\", \"moz:firefoxOptions\": {\"binary\":\"C:\\\\Firefox\\firefox.exe\"}}"
```